# solve an integral equation by python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I need to solve an integral equation by python 3.2 in win7.

I want to find an initial guess solution first and then use "fsolve()" to solve it in python.

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize.minpack import fsolve
from cmath import cos, exp
from scipy.integrate.quadpack import quad

def integrand2(x, b):
    return exp(-x)/b 

def intergralFunc2(b):
    integral,err = quad(integrand2, 0, 10, args=(b))  // **error here** 
    return 0.01 - integral

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def findGuess():
    vfunc = np.vectorize(intergralFunc2)
    f = np.linspace(-20, 20,10)
    plt.plot(f, vfunc(f))
    plt.xlabel('guess value')
    plt.show()

def solveFunction():
    y= fsolve(intergralFunc2, 10)
    return y


if __name__ == '__main__':
    findGuess()
    solution = solveFunction()
    print("solution is ", solution)
```

I got error:

```
 quadpack.error: Supplied function does not return a valid float.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't mix the functions from `cmath` with NumPy/SciPy because they don't work on NumPy arrays.  (This is not the only cause of your problem.)  You should only use `from ... import` to import modules from packages, and then use qualified names to access the functions -- otherwise, you'll get quite a few name clashes between NumPy and standard library functions.

Comment: try to do `from numpy import cos, exp` instead of using `cmath`

Comment: it works, thanks ! But, I got the same error when I made a change of integrand2 so that I can solve an integral equation embedded with another integral eq. I will make a new post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just made the following change and it should work (it worked for me).

remove:

```
from cmath import exp, cos
```

include:

```
from numpy import exp, cos
```

as explained in the comments, the `cmath` functions accept only `float` inputs, not arrays.